# Calling Twitter API from Google Apps Script

Tags: twitter, google-apps-script, twitter-oauth

I am trying to call Twitter's REST API from Google Apps Script.
The code I am using is copied one to one from here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external

and specifically:

```
function test() {
  var consumerKey = 'XXXX';     // Copied from my twitter app setting.
  var consumerSecret = 'XXXXX'; // Copied from my twitter app setting.
  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService('twitter');
  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl('http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token');
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl('http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token');
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl('http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize');
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
  var options = {
      'oAuthServiceName' : 'twitter',
      'oAuthUseToken' : 'always'
  };

  var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?count=5&include_entities=false&result_type=recent&q=hello';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var tweets = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(tweets)  
}
```

Nevertheless, I get Oauth ERROR every time I run it.
My settings in the twitter app allows for "Read and Write"

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to your twitter application and set the callback url as
https://script.google.com

[image: set the callback url as the image]

Comment: Would this be able to transfer to anything like jQuery?

Comment: Didn't understand you question. Can you explain it in a more detailed way?

Comment: As in more the concept of calling external libraries/APIs (jQuery being one example unlikely to work because of DOM manipulation). Don't worry about answering that question, since I misunderstood your response to the original question.

Comment: @braraujo Can we specify that callbackurl in the twitter request itself? The comment below that Callback URL reads that we need to specify explicitly oauth_callback URL in oAuth 1.0a

Answer (score 0):

This is now best handled through the following open source Google Apps Script library:

https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth1

The example in the documentation is twitter itself (because it's probably the only remaining user of oauth v1 out there...)

Cheers, M